# run java app on unix machine a :> sign to input something

Tags: java, unix, command

I run my java application on unix machine. After I input the command, it show me ">" sign. It seems I am in a interactive state with my application, but my application shouldn't interact with me. Instead, it just write something to files.

```
root@ip...:/mnt/test/java -cp "./" pack.foo
>
```

On windows machine, it just works file.

I also tried:

```
nohup root@ip...:/mnt/test/java -cp "./" pack.foo &
```

but still

Comment: What is "pack.foo"? Perhaps you should show us your expected output...

Comment: "Perhaps a game, Joshua?"

Answer (score 1):

On any UNIX system, the java syntax should be:

```
javac -cp <classpath of application> MyClass.java

java -cp <same classpath as above> MyClass
```

the second command should just be the name of the .class file you are attempting to run, and if everything is in the current directory, the argument for -cp should be "." without quotation marks

```
java -cp . MyClass
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, removing quotes resolved the problem. It works now.